# Unable to install lp_solve 5.5 extension on my WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, lpsolve

I want to install and run lp_solve through PHP for a project I am working on. I've already created the solver in C and will be then working on converting it to PHP (and maybe even try incorporating a MySQL table to list off the array, it seems like a clever idea at the moment....)

I followed the documentation here yet when I test the installation I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function lpsolve() in file location

I am running WAMP 3.1.0 64 bit with the following software versions: Apache 2.4.27 - PHP 7.1.9 from a Windows 8 PC.

In case I missed or mis-understood any of the steps in the documentation, here is what I have done:

1. Downloaded lpsolve55.dll from here and copied it into my System32
   folder
2. Identified the directory where the loadable extensions reside
   i.e. c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.9/ext/ from my php.ini folder
3. Copied php_phplpsolve55.dll to the folder above
4. Added extension=php_phplpsolve55.dll to my php.ini folder
5. Re-started WAMP with all associated services

Yet the above fatal error keeps recurring. I have tried changing to an older PHP version 5.6.31 which is enabled on my WAMP server without much luck.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: First off i dont think it has been compiled for PHP 7 or above.

Comment: And it does not look like it is being maintained, well not recently anyway

Comment: Dear Codingmedic did you managed to make lpsolve work in php?